# strip_tags in php doesnt help, need a better alternative

Tags: php, strip-tags

I got a form value in which I need to strip html tags and not the other things.

Example: I pass following in textarea

```
<h1> test </h1> Testing <5 years or >2 years.
```

I need to get following outcome

```
test Testing <5 years or >2 years.
```

When I try strip tags it removed 5 years also which I dont want. Many thanks for those who help on this.!

Comment: As you may have noticed from the syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow, your snippet is invalid HTML. The parser trying to interpreting the `<5 years` as a tag.

Comment: You may need to escape any `<`s and `>`s that aren't tags and therefore you want to keep. Replace them with their HTML encoded equivalents: `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Hi @NatRiddle I tried to replace < and > as you suggested but still I dont get what I expect. The main aim is that I wanted to strip html tags and keep > and < symboled texts

Comment: This is not possible in a general manner. Your input is mixed content, there is no general (html centric) tool that can distinguish between what should get interpreted as html markup and what should _not_ get interpreted that way. So either you have to provide additional information or you need to manually process that input.

Comment: @arkascha thanks got it but when you say additional information. You wanted more info to solve this or we must ask the user to key in with some constrains, Because the User may key it value as I shared. It should ignore html and take less than or greater than symbols

Comment: If this is user input (html user input never is a good idea...) then you will need to tell the user that he needs to use valid html. The string you posted is invalid html markup. There is no sense in trying to "fix" something that is invalid. What I asked for is whether _you_ (not your user) can give additional information about how to interpret the input.

Comment: @arkascha User give this not as html input. But my earlier code which have strip_tags removes user input which starts with less than and ends with greater than. i.e., "<5 years or > 2 years" becomes "2 years". Wanted to solve this

Comment: Sorry, but that last comment is very confusing. So the user just enters the "<5 years or >2"? Or is there no user input at all and you just mentioned that form for fun? Please use the "edit" button below your question, revise it, be precise and say what your actual question is and what you actual situation is. Everything else is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pre-process the HTML to convert the open and closing angle brackets that do not comprise valid HTML tags to entities prior to calling strip_tags. There are a number of ways to do this, but the easiest and most reliable is probably to use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). HTML purifier is smart enough to entity encode the greater-than and less-than in your string, while leaving the H1 tags intact. You can then strip tags, and if you need to have the angle brackets restored, use [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).